# No required "Session Timeout",

Tags: asp.net, .net, session, session-timeout

In my project session was only available for 30 minutes **(Which is by default).**

BUT... I want to disable this kind of session timeout. Means I required unlimited time for session by which my website never get log-in process again.

Comment: you cannot set session time out to unlimited..

Comment: which version of asp.net frame work r u using. Framework 4 has 20 minutes default. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756910/session-time-out-in-asp-net-4-0-on-iis-7-5

Comment: @Shekhar I am using 4.0 framework. i tried <sessionState timeout="525600"></sessionState> also but it's again required log-in process in 2 or 3 hours.

Answer (score 4):

### NEVER do this!

If user press *X button* on his browser his session (and all it's objects) will always be kept in server memory!

The solution is [**keeping ASP.NET Session alive** using this simple javascript hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431733/keeping-asp-net-session-open-alive), not making extremely long sessions.

Javascript forces the page to post empty data to the server, it's a kind of ping.
Server doesn't post anything back but the session timeout is automatically resetted.
You can configure session time on 20 mins, and ping timer on 19 mins.

Answer (score 1):

try that it increase timeout. if you want to store login info use cookies

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
  <sessionState timeout="525600"></sessionState>
 </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: by this session is time out at 120 minutes. But i required unlimited.

Comment: You can not set unlimited. For what you want there are other techniques such as cookies.

Comment: If existing unlimited then your server after some time would "burn".

Comment: I had tried this but after 2 to 3 hours session was expired.

Answer (score 1):

try this
maximum session timeout

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
     <sessionState timeout="525600"></sessionState>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I had tried this but after 2 to 3 hours session was expired.

Comment: it is maximum value of 365 days

Comment: When I used this then server session time out after 2 -4 hours.