# Unlimited session timeout in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need to keep the session of my application alive.  I have seen that it can be set to a certain time by implementing the following code:

```
Sub Session_OnStart
    Session.Timeout = 90
End Sub
```

Is there any way to make in unlimited?
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [No required "Session Timeout",](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17105807/no-required-session-timeout)

Comment: [MS forums.asp.net](http://forums.asp.net/t/1285066.aspx?unlimited%20session%20timeout%20)

Comment: Can I ask why you need this.

Comment: I explain you my requirement, may be you can advise me something.
I need to send an email message to user every 10 minutes.  Code is in Global.asax.
As long as session runs, it works fine.  When session is closed, it stops working.

Comment: Perhaps you should move your code so that it fires on Application_Start and Stop instead of Session_Start Stop? Better still just have a timer object in a separate class. The session stopping will not affect it then

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion is a really bad idea to make the session unlimited, the best thing you can do is to store the login information and restore the session when an user postback in your site, so you don't need the iis to set high timeout times.

Comment: btw is not possible to set unlimited timeout, you must use a js for postback at a given time

Comment: javascript, you can try to see there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431733/keeping-asp-net-session-open-alive

Answer (score 0):

If not possible why not alert user that session is about to time out

[Session Timeout Warning in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522482/session-timeout-warning-in-asp-net)

Comment: and how to refresh a minute before it expires?

Comment: @Furqan Sehgal: if you follow this link it will give you all the info you need [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/227382/Alert-Session-Time-out-in-ASP-Net] the code is JavaScript, place code in the head of ur html