# Session getting expired in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session, web-config

I am having an `asp.net` website. I have set `Session Timeout` in `webconfig` to `60min` but still if I keep browser ideal for even 10-15 min my session gets expire and website gets Logout. Why is this happening can anyone please suggest

`webconfig`

```
<system.web>
<sessionState timeout="60" />    
</system.web>
```

Comment: You can reefer this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756910/session-time-out-in-asp-net-4-0-on-iis-7-5)

Comment: Also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648992/session-timeout-in-asp-net?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this 
Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> IIS Manager -> Select desired web site -> in ASP.NET section on right side open Session State -> and finally, in text box named "Time-out (in minutes)"

another way

  
      `