# How to change session in orchard cms

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I use Orchard Cms.I want to Increase the timeout in this Cms.But I don't know how to change the timeout.How can to change the session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the session timeout in web.config or in IIS itself.

For example: [Session Time out in IIS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/949426/3936440)